# Firefox status bar is 3/4" above the bottom border

Tags: firefox

Somehow my FireFox 2 got corrupted, and the status bar is about 3/4" above the bottom window border.
Anyone have an idea on how to get it back to being flush with the bottom window border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it is programming-related... but:

```
firefox -safe-mode
Reset toolbar and control
```

More at [Firefox support](http://support.mozilla.com/fr/kb/Firefox+window+is+too+large+or+opens+off+screen)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I reset the toolbar and controls.  That didn't work, so I re-ran it and disabled the addons.  That fixed it.  Then I re-enabled my addons and all was well.

Comment: disabling the add-ons! Right, I had forgotten that one: it is indeed the next logical step to be in a real 'safe-mode'. Thank you for that feedback.